# Encapsulating CTRL-SHIFT-A-D in a java String

Tags: java, unicode

I use a ssh library with java to connect to a server. I want to detach a GNU Screen with CTRL-SHIFT-A-D, why I need to send this sequence to the server.

Can someone tell me how I can write this in a Java String? I looked through the unicode and ascii tables but I couldn't find a hint.

Sincerely,
Heinrich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [ASCII table](http://www.bbdsoft.com/ascii.html).

```
CTRL-A is 2
CTRL-D is 4
```

Is there a reason you need a SHIFT? In my terminal ssh is terminated with ctrl-a ctrl-d.

Comment: I was confused, thats the solution!